# Distributed Computing not working in PowerWorld Simulator21

Tags: power

Not sure whether to post this here or in another part of Stack Exchange, PowerWorld itself is used widely in analyzing large scale power grids.

I am trying to run a contingency analysis in PowerWorld Simulator21, but when I try to set up distributed computing (parallel processing) I get the following error:

DistVerify ERROR: Machine localhost failed verification with error "No such interface supported".

Has anyone encountered something like this, and if so were you able to correct it? I am using Windows.

Comment: which OS are you using? ... is it Windows?

Comment: @jsotola yes I am using Windows 10

Comment: i could very well be wrong about this ... it may have something to do with the loopback interface which is localhost ... windows does not have it enabled by default .... google `win 10 loopback interface`

Comment: So it seems the issue was related to a license verification issue, after re-running the SimAuto registration tool it worked fine. Pretty odd.